# Dificuldade em gerar um objeto JSON na ordem correta

Tags: java, json, java-ee

**Estou tentando gerar um objeto JSON, seguindo esse modelo:**

```
{
    "schemas": [
        "urn:ietf:params:scim:schemas:extension:oracle:2.0:OIG:User",
        "urn:ietf:params:scim:schemas:core:2.0:User",
        "urn:ietf:params:scim:schemas:extension:oracle:2.0:IDM:User",
        "urn:ietf:params:scim:schemas:extension:enterprise:2.0:User"
    ],
    "urn:ietf:params:scim:schemas:extension:oracle:2.0:OIG:User": {
        "userLoginAttemptsCounter": 0,
        "ldapCommonNameGenerated": 0,
        "userPasswordResetAttemptsCounter": 0,
        "ldapCommonName": "System Administrator",
        "passwordWarnDate": "2015-06-30T01:51:27.000-07:00",
        "lastSuccessfulLoginDate": "2015-03-11T00:00:00.000-07:00",
        "homeOrganization": {
            "value": "1",
            "$ref": "http://HOST_NAME:PORT/idaas/im/scim/v1/Organizations/1"
        },
        "passwordPolicyDescription": [
            {
                "value": "Password must not match or contain first name."
            }
        ],
        "disabled": false,
        "dataLevel": "2",
        "organizations": [
            {
                "value": "1",
                "$ref": "http://HOST_NAME:PORT/idaas/im/scim/v1/Organizations/1",
                "display": "Xellerate Users"
            }
        ]
    }

}
```

**porém estou chegando nesse modelo:**

```
{
    "schema": [
        "urn:ietf:params:scim:schemas:extension:oracle:2.0:OIG:User",
        "urn:ietf:params:scim:schemas:core:2.0:User",
        "urn:ietf:params:scim:schemas:extension:oracle:2.0:IDM:User",
        "urn:ietf:params:scim:schemas:extension:enterprise:2.0:User"
    ],
    "urn:ietf:params:scim:schemas:extension:oracle:2.0:OIG:User": {
        "userLoginAttemptsCounter": 0,
        "ldapCommonNameGenerated": 0,
        "passwordWarnDate": "2015-06-30T01:51:27.000-07:00",
        "homeOrganization": {
            "value": "1",
            "$ref": "http:\\HOST_NAME:PORT\\idaas\\im\\scim\\v1\\Organizations\\1"
        },
        "lastSuccessfulLoginDate": "2015-03-11T00:00:00.000-07:00",
        "organizations": [
            {
                "display": "Xellerate Users",
                "value": "1",
                "$ref": "http://HOST_NAME:PORT/idaas/im/scim/v1/Organizations/1"
            }
        ],
        "disabled": false,
        "ldapCommonName": "System Administrator",
        "passwordPolicyDescription": [
            {
                "value": "Password must not match or contain first name."
            }
        ],
        "userPasswordResetAttemptsCounter": 0,
        "dataLevel": "2"
    }
}
```

**Meu código:**

```
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.simple.JSONArray;
import org.json.simple.JSONObject;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws JSONException {

        //obj principal
        JSONObject obj = new JSONObject();
        //obj usuario
        JSONObject objuser = new JSONObject();
        objuser.put("userLoginAttemptsCounter", 0);
        objuser.put("ldapCommonNameGenerated", 0);
        objuser.put("userPasswordResetAttemptsCounter", 0);
        objuser.put("ldapCommonName", "System Administrator");
        objuser.put("passwordWarnDate", "2015-06-30T01:51:27.000-07:00");
        objuser.put("lastSuccessfulLoginDate", "2015-03-11T00:00:00.000-07:00");


        JSONObject objcompuser = new JSONObject();
        objcompuser.put("value", "1");
        objcompuser.put("$ref", "http:\\HOST_NAME:PORT\\idaas\\im\\scim\\v1\\Organizations\\1");


        objuser.put("homeOrganization", objcompuser);

        JSONObject psw_des = new JSONObject();
        psw_des.put("value", "Password must not match or contain first name.");

        JSONObject org_des = new JSONObject();
        org_des.put("value", "1");
        org_des.put("$ref", "http://HOST_NAME:PORT/idaas/im/scim/v1/Organizations/1");
        org_des.put("display", "Xellerate Users");
        //obj headers
        JSONArray headers = new JSONArray();
        headers.add("urn:ietf:params:scim:schemas:extension:oracle:2.0:OIG:User");
        headers.add("urn:ietf:params:scim:schemas:core:2.0:User");
        headers.add("urn:ietf:params:scim:schemas:extension:oracle:2.0:IDM:User");
        headers.add("urn:ietf:params:scim:schemas:extension:enterprise:2.0:User");
        obj.put("schema", headers);
        obj.put("urn:ietf:params:scim:schemas:extension:oracle:2.0:OIG:User", objuser);

        JSONArray objpass = new JSONArray();
        objpass.add(psw_des);
        JSONArray objorg = new JSONArray();
        objorg.add(org_des);

        objuser.put("passwordPolicyDescription", objpass);
        objuser.put("disabled", false);
        objuser.put("dataLevel", "2");
        objuser.put("organizations", objorg);
        System.out.println(obj.toJSONString());
    }
}
```

*Obs(estou usando a lib simple-json)*

Comment: Acho que não tem como escrever um JSON sempre na mesma ordem (a não ser que vc escreva na mão.. Usar um StringBuilder e ir populando tudo na mão). Até porque, a ideia do JSON não é que a ordem dos atributos seja relevante.. Então acho que não tem muito jeito mesmo não...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

De acordo com a [especificação do JSON](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7159):

> An object is an unordered collection of zero or more name/value pairs, where a name is a string and a value is a string, number, boolean, null, object, or array.

Ou seja: a ordem dos valores de um objeto é irrelevante, pois um objeto é uma coleção não ordenada. Você não deveria precisar se preocupar com isso.

---

Se você **realmente** precisa de um JSON ordernado para algum **serviço que foi implementado de forma errada**, você pode usar um [LinkedHashMap](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/LinkedHashMap.htmlcad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwjCs5-j5NTXAhXMnJAKHblHCqUQFggzMAE&url=https%3A%2F%2Fdocs.oracle.com%2Fjavase%2F8%2Fdocs%2Fapi%2Fjava%2Futil%2FLinkedHashMap.html&usg=AOvVaw1K0d674y-ujTmeb9ex3MzA) ao criar seu JSONObject.

Comment: Sim verdade conforme o @IgorVenturelli disse, para o meu objetivo é mais fácil montar na mão com o StringBuilder.

Comment: Como eu disse acima, você pode continuar usando exatamente a mesma biblioteca, alterando somente como o JSONObject é criado. Não há necessidade de fazer tudo manualmente.